# Deleted files in main repo do not get deleted in the dist repo

Tags: git, workflow

Please see following workflow file, which is responsible for rsyncing (compiled) files from my main repository to my dist repository:

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "master"
      - "dev"

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Checkout the source repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
        path: src

  - name: Setup node
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: 14

  - name: Build the source
    run: |
      cd src
      npm ci
      npm run webpack:build
      cd ..

  - name: Checkout the dist repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: xxx
      path: dist
      ssh-key: ${{ secrets.xxx_DIST_PUSH_KEY }}
      ref: ${{ github.ref }}

  - name: Commit and push the changes to the dist repo
    run: |
      rsync -r src/shopify/ dist/

      cd src
      commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
      cd ../dist

      git config user.name github-actions
      git config user.email github-actions@github.com
      git add .
      git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "Built $commit"
      git push
```

How can i change this workflow file so it also deletes files on my dist repo, if they were deleted on my main repo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-add%5D+deleted+files

Comment: This: `git add -A .`

Comment: This didn't work, but changing my rsync did: rsync -v -r --delete --exclude=.git/ src/shopify/ dist/